# DC to DC power supply Virtual Ground circuit dillema

Tags: dc-dc-converter, isolation, virtual-ground

I am trying to power a circuit with two op-amps that require multiple voltages. The voltage requirements are -14v, +14v, ground/24+. I am trying to power this circuit from a 12vdc power supply.

I am using a 14vdc to 24dc boost module to obtain 28v and a rail splitter circuit to create a virtual ground for the -14v and +14v and its working. I am using 24v from the dc to dc boost to supply the board for the 24vdc requirment.

The problem I am having is the input/output negative(common) from the power supply through the DC TO DC board connects to the virtual ground circuit input and output 14v-. This rail cannot connect to the negative ground common, this is my problem.

So my logic is to isolate the dc to dc input from the output and this will in turn eliminate the -14v from being connected to the 12v negative ground common?

I think this will work but how can I achieve this? I already have the dc to dc board and the virtual ground board. Is there a simple electrical circuit I can make to add isolation or a whole other idea that doesnt require me to have to use a dc to dc board that has isolated negative input/output?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Newbie

[image][image: dual rail splitter]

Comment: Me thinks you are asking way too much of those components. You can do one (splitter) or the other (booster) but not in conjunction at the load end. Does it really need to be 14 or can u get away with +/-12V

Comment: i could get a way with +/-12 at slightly diminished performance. Can you explain splitter? At this point im all ears....

Comment: See answer with my comment.

Comment: See single-supply op-amp application-note on Google.  It is your friend.

Comment: What is the 24V used for if I might ask....?

Comment: ME thinks the reason we are asking about what the 24V is being used for is because there may be a way to change the bias on that part to use +/-12V instead. But it depends on what it's for.

Comment: To be honest to help you further I would really need to see the specs on that converter you have, and more info on that you are driving with them. I have a string suspicion you may be able to can get away with just the +24V converter and using the +12 as your virtual ground.

Comment: Or is that a module too?

Comment: This would work if you are building a circuit board.

Answer (score 2):

Use two DC-DCs instead.. much simpler and saves all that messing around with the ground.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54974/discussion-on-answer-by-trevor-dc-to-dc-power-supply-virtual-ground-circuit-dill).

Answer (score 0):

It would be MUCH simpler to use DC-DC voltage inverter to get -12V from your +12V and use that to power your device.

If it works with +14V it will probably work with +12V.

You can use:

- a charge pump
- an inverting DC-DC (called inverting buck boost) which can be designed to output +14V if you want
- an isolated DC-DC

Choice of topology will depend on current draw from device.

Comment: Yes @peufeu that was where I was headed. Use 2 DC-DCs. One inverting to -12V the other Boosting to  +24.

Comment: Sorry, saw your message after writing. Also, requirements are not clear: if OP uses a virtual ground, then we dont know if the +24 shall be referenced to virtual GND or to the other GND... not to mention to what GND the analog IO shall be referenced!

Comment: the -/+ 14 is 300-500ma and the 24v is 5a....I was looking at the charge pump and islolated dc-dc before the post...I already have the dc-dc modules so I am trying to utilize them. They work on seperate 12v supplies but im trying to get it all to work on one supply.

Comment: OK; in the schematic you posted, please note that the orange "+28V", seen from your board's point of view, is actually +14V, since your board's GND is a virtual GND which is 14V above the power supply's GND... (ie, problem!)

Comment: A whooping 5A on 24V???? Why not use a 24V power supply instead of an expensive high current boost DCDC?

Comment: peufeu, 24v is referenced to ground and CT virtual ground connects to the same ground this is the problem.

Comment: peufe, 28v in orange is a mistake its actually 24v..

Comment: peufeu, I am trying to ake this circuit work on 12v for mobile application

Comment: What is the 24V load?

Comment: 24v power a darlinton pair that modulates a PA amplifiers collectors